# Simplifying sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \tfrac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} T_{jk}$

Tags: summation, summation-method

Let's say I have a $symmetric$ matrix with components $\{ T_{jk} \}_{j,k=1}^{n}$ satisfying $T_{jk} = T_{kj}$.

Is there any way to simplify the following summation?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \tfrac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} T_{jk}
$$

This is related to this one of my previous [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207416/simplifying-the-sum-sum-jk-t-jk-for-symmetric-t).

I have a hunch that I can get this into the form:
$$
\alpha \sum_{j,k=1}^{n} T_{jk} - \beta \sum_{j=1}^{n} T_{jj}
$$
for some constants $\alpha,\beta$. But I can't quite see how this would work. Is there a way to deal with such a summation?

Comment: @Smylic Thanks! It's fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no desired way to simplify this sum. It is pretty easy to see for $n = 3$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3} \tfrac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} T_{jk} = \frac12 T_{1, 2} + \frac13 T_{1, 3} + \frac13 T_{2, 3}.$$
And all these summands have the same coefficient $2\alpha$ in sum
$$\alpha \sum_{j,k=1}^{n} T_{jk} - \beta \sum_{j=1}^{n} T_{jj}.$$
Also these three summands with the same coefficients present for all $n \ge 3$.

However it is easy to see that for $n \le 2$ we have $\alpha = \beta = \frac14$.